# error -9999 when trying to write into int * on GTX 980 and OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I get error `-9999`

> ```
> Breakpoint 7, cl::detail::errHandler (err=-9999, errStr=0x43cc1f "clWaitForEvents") at /opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0-0-Be
> ta/include/CL/cl.hpp:321
> ```
>
> at `event.wait()` because of the following line
>
> ```
> valid[id] = 1;
> ```
>
> where valid is `__global int* valid`.

The .cl code is

```
__kernel void validateRecords(__global const char* buffer, __global const struct RecordInfo* allRecords, __global int* valid, const unsigned int n)
{
    const int id=get_global_id(0);

    if (id < n)
    {
            char* record = buffer[allRecords[id].position];
            int size = allRecords[id].length;

            int updateTimeLen = findFixed(record, size, ',');
            if(updateTimeLen == -1 || updateTimeLen != UPDATE_TIME_LEN)
            {
               valid[id] = 1;
               return;
            }
    }

}
```

and I get error

> `code -9999 at`valid[id] = 1.

I just noticed that if I comment //valid[id] = 1; or //int updateTimeLen = findFixed(record, size, ','); all is fine, but when both are used I get the above error.

The device is GTX 980 with OpenCL 1.1. Can you help please?

Comment: How does your host code look like? Did you miss any intialization parameters (input / output usage)?

Comment: Nope, all is well initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue. First of all, I am using the AMD SDK on Nvidia card. This worked well for me in the past (with GTX 780 Ti). However this time I noticed a few problems. The first one is this line:

```
char* record = buffer[allRecords[id].position];
```

which I initially (correctly) wrote as

```
char* record = buffer + allRecords[id].position;
```

but it didn't compile and I mechanically changed it to the above and it did compile. That was the first problem, but it had nothing to do with the error.

The second was that passing a __private char* continued to throw error -9999 no matter what I do (perhaps because of the different SDK, but it might be something else), so I passed the __global char* buffer to the function and all worked fine.